# Matrix multiplication ordering $(C^TC)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do you multiply the inside first, and then find the inverse of that? Is that the order done or does the inverse make it $(CC^T)$?

The full equation I'm doing is

$P_W = C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$

But for some reason the sizes aren't working out. My first step is doing the inside of $(C^TC)^{-1}$ and then finding the inverse of that. But when I multiply the inverse by C in front, the sizes don't multiply.

Comment: @Dr.MV That holds for square $C$. When computing a projection matrix, though, $C$ is often not square.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of doing the inside first and inversing should work. The sizes should work out no matter the size of the original matrix (see below for why), so you might be doing the matrix multiplication wrong. Hopefully this will show you where to look!(:

If C is (n by m)then $(C^T)C$ is (n by n) because the columns of C and the rows of $C^T$ determine the size of $(C^T)C$. This multiplication will work because the columns of $C^T$ = rows of C = m.

$(C^T)C$ is therefore invertible (as long as it is full rank) because it will always be square. $(C^TC)^{-1}$ will still be (n by n).

C$(C^TC)^{-1}$ will be (n by m), determined by the columns of $(C^TC)^{-1}$ and the rows of C. This multiplication will work because the columns of C = rows of $(C^TC)^{-1}$ = n.

$C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$ will be (m by m) determined by the columns of $C^T$ and the rows $C(C^TC)^{-1}$. This multiplication will work because the columns of $C(C^TC)^{-1}$ = rows of $C^T$ = n.